# generic compareTo sorting different object classes

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use compareTo to return the largest or maximum of various types of objects. This works for integers, strings, but I am having when I try to include circles...

How can I get one generic method to compare all objects? In this case circles only have one variable, radius, to compare...

```html
public class CompareToVariousObjects {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
 Integer[] numbers = {1, -2, 3, 0, -1, 2, -3};
 String[] colors = {"blue", "green", "white", "red", "black"};
 Circle[] circles = {new Circle(5.9), new Circle(.5), new Circle(1), 
   new Circle(2.5), new Circle(.1)};
 
 System.out.println("Numerically, the maximum number is: " + max(numbers));
 System.out.println("Alphabetically, the maximum color is: " + max(colors));
 System.out.println("The largest circle has a radius of: " + max(circles);
 }
 
 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T[] list) {
  T currentMax = null;
  int currentMaxIndex;
    
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
   currentMax = list[i];
   currentMaxIndex = i;
   
   for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
    if (currentMax.compareTo(list[j]) > 0) {
     currentMax = list[j];
     currentMaxIndex = j;
    }
   }
   
   if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
    list[currentMaxIndex] = list[i];
    list[i] = currentMax;
   }
  }
  return currentMax;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Collections.max` directly.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: Your method doesn't care if the objects are Integers, Strings, Circles, Bananas or Fishes. The only thing that matters is that they're all instances of Comparable, so they can always be compared to each other. BTW, any reason why you're reimplementing `Collections.max()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)? Why dos a method returning the max element of an array modifies this array?

Comment: Presumably your Circle class needs to implement `Comparable<Circle>` and then return the result of comparing the radii.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I get one generic method to compare all objects?"

There is no ONE generic way to compare objects , thats why compareTo and Comparable were made in the first place . Consider students in a class , i can compare them based on height , score , age ...

Just make a Class of w.e concept you want (say a circle) , implement Comparable and define compareTo to define the criteria for how u compare that Object. for example :

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
 int diameter;
 //constructor
 public int compareTo(Circle c) {
   if(c.diameter> this.diameter){
   return 1;
  }else if ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You must implement Comparable interface in Circle.